# Producing pdf with knitr and Rmarkdown: accents in text show up but not in figures.

Tags: r, pdf, knitr, r-markdown, tikz

Accents in paragraphs work perfectly. Text in figures is correct in the plot viewer, but once I compile the pdf the accents disappear from the figures.

Here's an example that reproduces the issue.

````
---
title: 'Some title'
author: 'This be me'
date: '`r format(Sys.Date(), "%B %Y")`'
lang: es
header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{tikz}
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
---


```{r global options, echo = F, message=F}
library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(fig.width=6, fig.height=3.5, dev = 'tikz')
```

I have some paragraphs that include cool accents like áspid. 

If I run the next chunk in the R console I see the accent on the figure it generated. But the accent is missing in the pdf. 


```{r}
plot(pressure, main= "áspid")
```
````

Comment: I think it is a simple encoding thing you need to account for..try using this older suggestion from the stacks : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146409/accent-in-knitr

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Wouldn't the encoding affect the whole document? Wouldn't wrong encoding mess up the accents in paragraphs too?

Comment: It might...it depends on the language you are using for the whole document, you might have options with and without the accents available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the R `tikzDevice` package.  It generates a `.tikz` file using the UTF-8 encoding, but doesn't include something like

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

in it to declare the encoding.  There are a number of references in its documentation to the "Unicode" section of the `?tikzDevice` help topic, but there is no such section.  You might want to report an issue on the Github page for the package, https://github.com/yihui/tikzDevice.

Edited to add:

After some experimentation, I can't see a way to add that line to the `.tikz` file, but requesting `xelatex` instead of the default LaTeX engine
does seem to work.  You can do that by adding the R code

```
options(tikzDefaultEngine = "xetex")
```

into your early code chunk.  That will use `xelatex` for the figures, `pdflatex` for the rest.  (`"xetex"` is not a typo; that's how you request `xelatex`.)

If you want, you can switch to `xelatex` for the rest using `latex_engine: xelatex` in the YAML header, but the figures will still use `pdflatex` unless you also add the option setting.

Comment: I didn't know about the `tikzDevice` package so thank you for sharing!