# Rmarkdown pdf kable with accents

Tags: r, pdf, latex, kable

I am trying to create a table with some text which have some characters that are not currently being recognized. I have included:

```
- \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

and my code:

```
kable(t(tabela.nIncendiosUrbanos),
      caption="\\label{tab:nIncendiosUrbanos} Adaptado de Anuário de Ocorrências de Protecção Civil - ANPC.",
      "latex", align="c", booktabs=TRUE, escape=FALSE) %>%
  kable_styling(latex_options = "striped", full_width = F)
```

where,

```
tabela.nIncendiosUrbanos <- data.frame(
      'Edifício de habitação'=c(7000, 7300, 7200, 7200, 7439),
      "Estacionamento"=c(65, 60, 80, 60, 55),
      "Edifício de Serviço"=c(270, 250, 167, 180, 235),
      "Equipamento Escolar"=c(120, 130, 130, 150, 161),
      "Equipamento Hospitalar e Lar de Idosos"=c(80, 95, 65, 100, 88),
      "Edifício de Espetáculos, Lazer e Culto Religioso"=c(70, 80, 65, 75, 69),
      "Hotelaria e Similares"=c(450, 490, 470, 430, 448),
      "Edifício Comercial"=c(430, 350, 300, 290, 290),
      "Edifício Cultural"=c(20, 25, 20, 30, 23),
      "Indústria, Oficina e Armazém"=c(1000, 1230, 1100, 1100, 1237)
    )
```

and the output I get is

[image: Screenshot of output]

Anyone can help me with a workaround, please?

Comment: This might be helpful in keeping accent marks in your tables: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46220592/7954106.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. I have tried it, but nothing has changed. 
`output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Overview

After reading [@user2554330](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2554330/user2554330)'s answer to [Producing pdf with knitr and Rmarkdown: accents in text show up but not in figures.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46201466/producing-pdf-with-knitr-and-rmarkdown-accents-in-text-show-up-but-not-in-figur), I used the GitHub version of the [`tikzDevice`](https://github.com/daqana/tikzDevice#tikzdevice) package to keep accent marks in figures produced from the [`.rmd`](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/) output. I also set `check.names = FALSE` when using [`data.frame()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/data.frame.html) to ensure the column names were not [coerced to be syntactically valid names](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/make.names.html).

[image: SS of Output]

## .rmd Code

````
---
title: 'Keeping Accent Marks in PDF Output'
author: 'Cowboy Bebop'
date: '`r format(Sys.Date(), "%B %Y")`'
output: pdf_document
---


```{r global options, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
# install this particular package from GitHub
# using the 'devtools' package
# install.packages( pkgs = 'devtools' )
devtools::install_github( repo = "daqana/tikzDevice" )

# load necessary packages
library( kableExtra )
library( knitr )
library( magrittr )
library( tikzDevice )

# requesting xelatex instead of the default LaTeX engine does seem to work
# thank you to SO for this answer 
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/46220592/7954106
options( tikzDefaultEngine = "xetex" )

# load neccesary data
tabela.nIncendiosUrbanos <- data.frame(
      'Edifício de habitação'        = c(7000, 7300, 7200, 7200, 7439),
      "Estacionamento"               = c(65, 60, 80, 60, 55),
      "Edifício de Serviço"          = c(270, 250, 167, 180, 235),
      "Equipamento Escolar"          = c(120, 130, 130, 150, 161),
      "Equipamento Hospitalar e Lar de Idosos"           = c(80, 95, 65, 100, 88),
      "Edifício de Espetáculos, Lazer e Culto Religioso" = c(70, 80, 65, 75, 69),
      "Hotelaria e Similares"        = c(450, 490, 470, 430, 448),
      "Edifício Comercial"           = c(430, 350, 300, 290, 290),
      "Edifício Cultural"            = c(20, 25, 20, 30, 23),
      "Indústria, Oficina e Armazém" = c(1000, 1230, 1100, 1100, 1237),
      # setting check.names equal to FALSE
      # to avoid coercing the column names
      # to be synatactically valid
      # for more info, see ?make.names
      check.names = FALSE )
```

# Produce a table using `knitr::kable()`

```{r Produce table}
kable( x = t( x = tabela.nIncendiosUrbanos)
       , caption = "\\label{tab:nIncendiosUrbanos} Adaptado de Anuário de Ocorrências de Protecção Civil - ANPC."
       , format = "latex"
       , align = "c"
       , booktabs = TRUE
       , escape = FALSE ) %>%
  kable_styling( latex_options = "striped"
                 , full_width = FALSE )
```
````

## Session Info

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] devtools_1.13.6  tikzDevice_0.12  magrittr_1.5     knitr_1.20      
[5] kableExtra_0.9.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_0.12.18      rstudioapi_0.7    xml2_1.2.0        hms_0.4.2        
 [5] munsell_0.5.0     rvest_0.3.2       viridisLite_0.3.0 colorspace_1.3-2 
 [9] R6_2.2.2          rlang_0.2.1       filehash_2.4-1    plyr_1.8.4       
[13] stringr_1.3.1     httr_1.3.1        tools_3.5.1       grid_3.5.1       
[17] withr_2.1.2       htmltools_0.3.6   yaml_2.1.19       digest_0.6.15    
[21] rprojroot_1.3-2   tibble_1.4.2      crayon_1.3.4      readr_1.1.1      
[25] memoise_1.1.0     evaluate_0.11     rmarkdown_1.10    stringi_1.2.4    
[29] compiler_3.5.1    pillar_1.3.0      scales_0.5.0      backports_1.1.2  
[33] pkgconfig_2.0.1
```

Comment: I have copied and pasted your suggestion in a new file, but the output was the same. I am still having the same strange output:
`Edif<U+00ED>cio de habita<U+00E7><U+00E3>o`
Am I missing something?

Comment: @SergioCavaleiroCosta our versions of packages or `R` itself may differ. Please cross reference the output of `sessionInfo()` with the one I have added to this answer.

Comment: It may also be helpful to know that my RStudio version is 1.1.423.

Comment: Thank you so much! :D
I have updated both R and Rstudio, and it started working.